# Convert a simple array to json in php

Tags: php, json, arrays

I have an array as,

```
either
eight
einstein
eighth
```

When I convert it to json using json_encode I get the below output,

```
["either","eight","einstein","eighth"]
```

But I would like to have a structure like below

```
[
    {"name":"either"},
    {"name":"eight"},
    {"name":"einstein"},
    {"name":"eighth"}
]
```

How to get such a json? is there any function in php to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 4):

You just massage the array a little with `array_map` before converting it. You want to go from this structure (in PHP terms):

```
[
    "either",
    "eight",
    "einstein",
    "eighth"
]
```

to this:

```
[
    ["name" => "either"],
    ["name" => "eight"],
    ["name" => "einstein"],
    ["name" => "eighth"],
]
```

Once you know what must be done, doing it is easy:

```
$arr = ["either","eight","einstein","eighth"];
$arr = array_map(function($v) { return ['name' => $v]; }, $arr);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't redefine array keys like that, it would be an object in JavaScript by the way, but you can have a name array with those children:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "name" => array(
        "either",
        "eight",
        "einstein",
        "eighth"
    )
);

Echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/68295

Or, each line **could** be its own array with name keys.